# Deserializing a badly formed result

Tags: json-deserialization

I'm in the process of making a RESTful client (consumption side) and so far I have all my requests and responses fairly consistent.  I have something like this:

```
public class RESTClient
{
    public T Execute<T>(RESTRequest request);
}
```

My `RESTRequest` contains things like the base URI, authentication, resource URI and any object(s) to serialize. So far so good, until I came across a situation where the result can't be deserialized to a concrete type.  This result is a collection of, for example, `SomeClass` with (at the same level) the number of results in the collection. So let's say `SomeClass` looks like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I request the specific resource, then it deserializes perfectly fine - but I can't do that unless I have the ID, so for that I need to get it from a list that when requested returns JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "-1":
    {
        "id": -1,
        "name": "There is *always* a -1 in the collection as default"
    },
    "3":
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "This would be one I've added later"
    },
    "recordsCount": 2
}
```

So as you can see the ID of the object is the name of the object... and at the same level we have `recordsCount` which is just an `int`.

#### First Attempt

My first attempt was (as I'm working with JSON.Net) was to go through the result as `JObject` first, check if the name of the current object matched my selector and then do another request for `SomeClass` by ID to get the nicely deserialized concrete class.  Basically trawling through the JSON until I find something I can deserialize to my target class.

#### Second Attempt

After refactoring the first attempt (and decoupling my serializer from JSON.Net) I decided to pass in a custom serializer (say `SomeClassSerializer`) via the `RESTRequest` itself, so in *most* cases I can use the basic `JSON <--> Concrete` version, and when I need to I can override it with this specific one.

My actual questions are:

1. Am I alone in thinking this particular JSON response is just a horrible mess?  What were they thinking?!
2. Is there a better way of handling this (either in JSON.Net or not)... because the names of the objects are integers (and just so happen to be the ID) I can't exactly return them as `IEnumerable<TWeirdType>`.

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a lot simpler (and more obvious) than I initially thought... I wanted a solution that would keep my `RESTClient` and JSON.Net loosely coupled, and I can do just that with `JsonConverter` (which is part of JSON.Net but the logic is outside of my client and all happens through type).

What I've got instead is:

```
public interface IMySerializer
{
    string Serialize<T>(T target);
    T Deserialize<T>(string json);
}
```

Which is used by my `RESTClient` with a concrete type of `BasicJsonSerializer` (which has JSON.Net's serializer inside it) and this custom converter (passed through `JsonSerializerSettings`).

```
public IEnumerableSomeClassConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {}

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Handle the weirdness here and return my IEnumerable
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {}
}
```

Handling it very well.